# Getting distinct values from ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an author model that has posts with comments
The following works well but some times returns duplicates

```
author = Author.first
author.posts.not_deleted.where(written_at: from..to).includes(:comments).order(:id, 'comments.id')
```

It returns an `"ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation"`

When I am trying to use distinct

```
author.posts.not_deleted.where(written_at: from..to).includes(:comments).order(:id, 'comments.id').distinct
```

I get `Post::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fdc66b22bc8>`

How can I use distinct on my query in order to get distinct posts?

Comment: Are you trying to get distinct comments or distinct posts? Are you noticing duplicate records with the same id or something else?

Comment: I am trying to get distinct Posts